# How to configure alias subfolder with Google Cloud Platform App Engine app.yaml?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I'm very new to the Google Cloud Platform App Engine. Managed to serve a static web site on the App Engine. But now, I need to deploy an application that will have static HTML web-site at the root level and a subfolder that will be running a PHP application in that folder.

So the domain.com will serve static HTML web-site and domain.com/blog will serve PHP application.

**Folder structure**:

```
[Root]
    -index.html
    [blog]
         -index.php
```

**app.yaml**:

```
runtime: php72 # Replace with php73 to use the PHP 7.3 runtime

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

  # Serve blog 
- url: /blog/.*
  script: /www/blog/\1

  # Blog default
- url: /blog/
  script: /www/blog/index.php
```

Configured app.yaml like that but still getting 404 not found.

Comment: Is the www.domain.com working with this setup or both are giving status 404?

Comment: Could you please share the error? Please also deploy with the verbosity=debug flag (gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug) and share the output.